# How to find Virtual key Code of keys i.e 0x41

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to find the Virtual key Value of a key with javascript that will return eg-"`0x41`" instead of "`65`" ("`A`") for characters? I have tried `.keyup(e)` but it gives me "`65`" instead of "`0x41`". Would anyone know what could be done?

Comment: Convert it Decimal -> Heximal and possibly pad it. :)

Comment: `0x41` is Oct format of number, but it's dec 33 (hex 21), not 65.

Comment: @Justinas `0x41` is most typically used for hex, and that is indeed the hexadecimal value for the decimal `65`. The prefix `0o` is used in JavaScript for octal numbers and it's common in other languages, too. `0o101` would be the octal representation of the decimal `65`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has a built in library for this conversion of hex/dec; check it out.

```
const dectohex = (decimalnum) => decimalnum.toString(16);
const hextodec = (hexnum) => parseInt(hexnum, 16);

console.log(dectohex(65));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! The first comment gave me an idea of what needed to be done and i got it. Appreciate you for your time